# Chrome sluggish and not repainting non-webGL when drawing webGL in a tight loop

Tags: html, google-chrome, webgl

I have a page http://williame.github.com/Mandel_1 that draws an animating webGL scene using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://github.com/williame/Mandel_1/blob/99dc8bc412fcc0419d3ccac0b0daf8ca5b7f4b08/index.html#L486).  This is the [generally recommended approach](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_recommended_way_to_implement_a_rendering_loop.3F).

Occasionally it updates a div-element beside the canvas.

In Firefox, this works well, although the Firefox address bar can be sluggish to focus.

In Chrome, the div often doesn't get repainted despite being updated and the whole of Chrome can become sluggish and unresponsive.  I get reports of this from people on both Linux and Windows.

Additionally, the FPS I compute (by periodically counting how many frames in the previous 3 seconds) does not match the FPS that Chrome's own debug FPS counter shows.  The discrepancy is enough to make me wonder if Chrome is measuring something else?

How can I structure my draw-loop to keep Chrome and other browsers responsive whilst drawing at as good a frame-rate as possible?

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem on the Mac, so if it's only Linux and Windows, this might be related to some of the compositor changes that haven't been enabled on the Mac yet. When I go to about:flags and enable threaded compositing (which I believe is enabled by default on Win and Linux), the browser does become very sluggish (though it's hard to evaluate "the div often doesn't get repainted"). Is that the same behavior you see?

This may be a bug...you should file it on Chrome at http://crbug.com/new/ You might search around first to see if anyone else has filed something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's going in in your app but it looks like each time you insert a div you are also compiling and linking 4 shaders and checking for success. Compiling and linking is slow.

Try compiling and linking all your programs at startup.

Or, conversely, if you are 100% sure they will compile and link then don't check the compile and link status in which case their compilation and linking will be 100% async relative to JavaScript.